# How to detect telegram commands and get separate params?

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
$message = "/register hello world 2021";
if (preg_match('/^\/([^\s@]+)@?(\S+)?\s?(.*)$/', $message, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /register hello world 2021
    [1] => register
    [2] => 
    [3] => hello world 2021
)
```

How to get each params from that string

```
Array
    (
        [0] => /register hello world 2021
        [1] => register
        [2] => hello
        [3] => world
        [4] => 2021
    )
```

Comment: You could remove the `/` and split on a space.

Comment: If there can be up to X optional arguments, add X optional groups, like in https://regex101.com/r/uWM6TR/1

Comment: Or like `(?:^\/|\G(?!^))[\h@]?\K[^\s@]+`  https://regex101.com/r/psJc6L/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not yield the full match in the result, but you know that there are matches passing the if clause.

Note that in the pattern that you tried, the `@` is outside of the caputure groups and is optional, but `\S` by itself can also match `@`.

```
(?:^/|\G(?!^))[\h@]?\K[^\s@]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^/` match `/` at the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close the group
- `[\h@]?\K` Match an optional space or @, then forget what is matched until so far
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or an @

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BgI4MT/1)

```
$message = "/register hello@there world 2021";
if (preg_match_all('~(?:^/|\G(?!^))[\h@]?\K[^\s@]+~', $message, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => register
    [1] => hello
    [2] => there
    [3] => world
    [4] => 2021
)
```